# Reduce Drop down Menu Width in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

i have used drop down menu. its have two  brands of column one watch another knife. previous watch have 5 column  drop down mega menu. i had removed two column. its now showing extra black space. how to remove it ? i have used menu-full-width when  i create menu . this is my site Link

> [Site LINk](http://www.watchedge.com/)

please help me ? how to reduce  extra black space drop down? watch brands ? any  idea about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a css issue. You need to edit two selectors.

First is the menu width. It's set to 100% which is why you're seeing black space. Edit this class below.:

```
.cap-primary-menu .menu > li.menu-full-width .cap-submenu-ddown {
    padding: 20px 25px 25px;
    width: 100%; // set this to auto or something smaller than 100%
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #fff;
}
```

The li tags within that menu are set to be divisible by five, minus some padding, which is why you see 18%. So you need to change this selector:

```
.cap-primary-menu .menu > li.menu-full-width .cap-submenu-ddown .container > ul > li {
    width: 18.297%; // change this to 30% and go from there.
}
```

Comment: i have added   but still showing black space

Comment: Check your cache. I'm seeing it as three columns without any extra space.